# filtering pandas dataframe failing to return records for value contained in field

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the code below which just filters a dataframe for a particular value.  But the code is returning 0 records, and I can’t see why since the value is clearly contained in the field.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
Code

df[df[‘blah_id’]==‘blahMEB’].head()



Example data:
Print df.blah_id[1:5]

9         7477
20     blahMEB 
24     blahMDR 
44     blahMAU 
Name: blah_id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series is indeed as in your output, then the logical reason is that there is whitespace you do not see. That is, perhaps one of the entries is `'blahMEB '`.

Using [`pd.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) will remove the whitespace. Try using instead

```
df[df['blah_id'].str.strip()=='blahMEB'].head()
```

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(blah_id=['blahMEB ', 'foo']))
>>> len(df[df['blah_id']=='blahMEB']), len(df[df['blah_id'].str.strip()=='blahMEB'])
(0, 1)
```